# Filtering custom post type on a combination of custom taxonomies and custom fields?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, meta-query

I have a custom post type "artist".

It has an associated custom taxonomy "artist_type" with terms "voice", "actor", "corporate"

An "artist" also has custom fields for gender, location, agerangefrom and agerangeto. The latter 2 fields stipulate the age range that an actor/artist can act in.

I'm displaying artists according to their artist_type taxonomy — so using taxonomy-artist-type.php to display "/artist_type/voices/" and "/artist_type/actors"/ and "/artist_type/corporate/"

That's all fine.

But I need to add in a filter so that a user can narrow down each of these three categories according to the custom fields mentioned above: gender, location etc

I came across a site here that does something similar here: http://artists.derricktalentelite.com.au/?post_type=actor&gender=male

I'm getting confused on how to set this up in my scenario. DO I need to be using meta_query and/or pre_get_posts?

The user needs to be able to combine filters, for e.g., on the voices page: male in the age range from 20-30 based in London. How do I formulate the query string in the url to pass these parameters?

Any clues on how best to proceed would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to proceed is with ajax and a tax_query. Pre_get_posts filter only makes sense if you want to change the query on the template hierarchy, so the 'standard' taxonomy.php stuff.

This approach:

1. make a page with that show the default list, so maybe 'all', just a simple post_type query. And a side menu with all your filters as links that can be clicked of course.
2. make a php file that gets a specific term or terms through a tax_query, using $_GET, something like this:

   ```
   <?php
       define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
       require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
       $gender = (isset($_GET['gender'])) ? $_GET['gender'] : 0;
       $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'artist',
   'tax_query' => array(
       array(
           'taxonomy' => 'artist_type',
           'field' => 'slug',
           'terms' => $gender
       )
   )
       );
       $tag_query = new WP_Query( $args );
       if ($tag_query->have_posts()) : while ($tag_query->have_posts()) :  $tag_query->the_post();
   ```

That's just a starting example. Expand it with other variables through $_GET and check which ones are using in the url (?gender=male&voice=something).

Be sure this loop has the exact same html structure as you initially loaded stuff, so probably just a loop of item divs.

1. Then use jquery to load the data in the file above, something like this:

   ```
   <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   var template_path = $('#template_path').html();
       $.querySort = {
       path_to_template: template_path,
       }

       $('.filter').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('active');
           var term = $(this).attr('data-gender');
   var query = '?term=' + term;
       $('#data_wrapper').animate({opacity: 0}, function() {
           $('#data_wrapper').append('<div id="loader"></div>');  
           $("#data_wrapper").load($.querySort.path_to_template + '/ajax_load_terms.php' + query, function() {
               $('#loader').remove();
               $("#data_wrapper").animate({opacity: 1}, function() { });
           });
       });
       return false; //prevents a link from being clicked, if needed

   });
   </script>
   ```

See how it loads the file you just created, here ajax_load_terms.php. It adds the query to the url, and takes the term from the selector you click, which looks like this in my example:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-gender="[php echo your term here]">
```

Also note that the js needs to know the path to the ajax file, which it gets from a hidden div on you main page like this

```
    <div style="display: none" id="template_path"><?php bloginfo('template_url') ?></div>
```

I hope you get the direction and are able to figure out the holes in the code, if not give me a shout, it's quite complicated by the looks of it, but it's not really.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks matiyin for your detailed response. I'll work through this and let you know how I go. It makes sense to use ajax here I think rather than pre_get_posts and the taxonomy template. How would I be adding in a meta_query in conjunction with the tax_query?